# How to use a custom js function in mongoose findByIdAndUpdate with $set

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to ask if there is a way to update the database document using a custom js function.
I know the find -> update the document with js -> update/save method and it creates problems with concurrent data updates.
I will depict my use case with code example below:

```
const customJSFunction = (savedResponses) => {
  // do something with savedResponses
  return updatedSavedResponses;
}

let test = await testModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
  'someId',
  {
    $set: {
      savedResponses: customJSFunction('$savedResponses'),
    },
  },
  {
    new: true,
  }
);
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Try [instance methods](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods).

Comment: @jQueeny,
I might not be able to explain my question properly. I don't think instance method can help me in my use case.
What I am trying to achieve is to not use the JSON format of mongoose/mongodb to update the object instead I would like to use JS to do so.
In order to do that I need to have the current value of savedResponses in my custom js function that I will call within my update query.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show what your custom JS function does as its likely there an equivalent mongodb native operator combination, or aggregation or mongoose method that will do the same job.

Comment: @jQueeny, 
I now understand that what I am expecting is not possible and the only solution would be to go with the aggregation pipeline.
Thank you for your help. I am now writing that logic of customJSFunction with aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I think @jQueeny has the right answer. Instance methods seem the way to go. but done a little different than you're thinking. without knowing the structure of your model/schema, here's an example.

we declare the schema:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  ...schema properties...
})
```

add method to your schema:

```
userSchema.methods.customJSFunction = function(id) {
  const oldDoc = userSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(id, () => { // we get our doc by id and either do our something here or pass in fromt he function
  return newDoc
})
```

}

declare model:

```
let model = new UserModel({
  prop1: 'thing in model',
  prop2: 'another thing in model'
})
```

Then call your method attached to the model:

```
let customThing = model.customJSFunction()
console.log(customThing) // Result: changed prop1 or prop2
```

you can see here for more in depth example/explanation:

https://javascript.plainenglish.io/create-own-method-in-mongoose-model-5fefa7975b9d

Comment: I might not be able to explain my question properly. I don't think instance method can help me in my use case.
Your answer is just to put the findByIdAndUpdate into the instance method. And I still have to use the JSON format query to update the results.
What I am trying to achieve is to not use the JSON format of mongoose/mongodb to update the object instead I would like to use JS to do so.
In order to do that I need to have the current value of savedResponses in my custom js function that I will call within my update query.